# Minimizing Disk Spaced used on Redshift Table

Tags: amazon-redshift

I'm working with machine telemetry data, so I've got a ton of time-series sensor readings for various runs of a process. I believe there are some disk usage savings to be had if I store the data differently but I'm a novice at DB optimization and encoding.

One table I'm looking at has ~11.6BN rows of the following:

| Column | Type | Encoding |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Time (seconds since start of run) | float8 | none |
| Sensor reading | float8 | none |
| GUID of run | varchar(256) | lzo |

I initially chose these column types because I wasn't sure the range of data I'd be getting in, but the time and sensor readings seem to max out at (8,3) unsigned and (5,2) signed, respectively, while the max GUID length is 45. There are ~2.5M unique runs represented here.

The table currently takes up ~260GB. My plan is to convert the floats to decimals and decrease the varchar length. Is this the right move? Are there any other changes I should be looking at, i.e. changes to the encoding?

Comment: Can you substitute the GUID with a surrogate integer column?

Comment: A varchar(256) doesn't take 256 bytes when the content is less than 256 bytes. And what problem are you trying to solve? 260GB is not that much and you might save some 10 to 20 percent when optimising, but it could be less. Table partitioning might be interesting, but that won't change anything in the usage of space. But without a problem, there ain't much to optimise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways that table space can be reclaimed.

First is compression (encoding) which you are looking at.  Best advice is to compress everything especially data columns.  There are only a few cases where storing raw data on disk is a win (sort key - usually second or third keys).  Run ANALYZE COMPRESSION  and get a report of what compression will be the best for your data.  As one commenter noted a surrogate integer may be best and that is one of the compression (encoding) modes that may be recommended.  This report will also give you some idea about how much space could be saved.  Changing the data type from float to some decimal representation will likely not save much space ONCE they are compressed.  I'd used the data type that is best for the work and leave the space savings up to compression.

Second I'd want to make sure that there isn't a lot of "dead space" in the table.  Redshift uses 1MB blocks to store data.  Once a block is written it is not updated, only replaced.  If you have a process that adds data incrementally to the table the last block is likely partially full but the next write will start a new block.  This can lead to a lot of dead space in the table.  "VACUUM " will compact the table to remove this dead space (or "VACUUM DELETE ONLY " if you are worried about the sorting time of the table).  Redshift should do this automatically now but it can be disabled and happens when there is low activity on the cluster which for some clusters is never.

Additional thing to check is if the table is well distributed as being poorly distributed can increase dead space as well as impact your query performance.

That's about it.  Redshift is all about packing in large data but you need to use its systems well.

Comment: This worked well for me. I was already VACUUMing regularly but ANALYZE COMPRESSION recommended zstd for the numerical columns, and once implemented the size dropped to 140GB. Along with the other tables I now have some room to operate without investing in additional/larger nodes.